# NodeJS module initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an npm module that I would like to configure once and call in multiple places.

The npm module (let's call it 'signature') is basically like this

```
module.exports = function(options) {
 return new Signature(options);
};

var Signature = function(options) { }
Signature.prototype.sign = function() {}
```

I made another module ('signer') to configure it:

```
var signature = require('signature');

module.exports = function() {
// I pass whatever config options here
return signature({});
};
```

In my code I do:

```
var signer = require('../utils/signer');
signer.sign();
```

However this gives me a "has no method "sign" error.  What am I doing wrong? I suspect I have to initialize something but not sure what. If I bypass the config module (signer) and just call the signature module then it works fine:

```
var signature = require('signature');
var s = signature();
s.sign();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signer exports a function that returns a signature. Try:

```
var signer = require('../utils/signer');
signer().sign();
```

Comment: Wouldn't that create a new instance of Signature each time? I am basically wanting to configure Signature once and have an easy way to call the ready made instance wherever. Perhaps I need to change my approach?

Comment: It would. From the sample you have provided, if you want signer to export a single instance you could change it to: module.exports = signature({});